# Does an abugida without inherent vowels qualify as an alphabet or an alphasyllabary?

Tags: terminology, orthography

Alphabets and alphasyllabaries seem functionally equivalent, but I am confused about the terminology. The coining of "abugida" including inherent vowels as part of the definition, but some alphasyllabaries lack inherent vowels (e.g. Akson Lao, Thaana) and some alphabets have inherent vowels (e.g. Fraser script/Old Lisu, Meroitic, Old Persian Cuneiform).

Are inherent vowels part of what defines alphasyllabaries, in comparison to alphabets, or an independent spelling rule that may be applied to either?

Is the "abugida" a subset of alphasyllabary defined by inherent vowels?

Comment: The core difference is that in alphabets, vowels have equal status as the consonants, also preserving the order of reading. Both are not the case with abugida. Not claiming that this is a full answer, however. Also, I don't think that inherent vowels change anything here; in modern Thai, one can explicitly write the inherent vowels (`ตก` → `โตกะ`), many dictionaries do so to denote syllabification of polysyllabic words and their pronunciation.

Comment: what do you mean by "inherent vowels"?  There is no such concept in traditional Arabic philology, I've never come across it in modern writings on Arabic either.

Comment: ps. the Arabic writing is definitely not syllabic, let alone alphasyllabic.

Comment: @mobileink: I never mentioned arabic?

Comment: fair enough, but it is often offered as an "abugida" system.  That term comes from the semitic tradition.  The traditional Arabic enumeration of "letters" is a life ba, jeem, dal ... whence "abjadiya", whence abugida.  This is not unique to Arabic

Comment: sorry, "alif,  ba, jeem, dal.. "

Comment: @mobileink: I used "abugida" derived from Ge'ez as coined by Peter T. Daniels to refer to the Brahmic, Ethiopian and Aboriginal Syllabics families of scripts. "Abjad" was similarly coined to refer to scripts without explicit vowels such as the Semitic families.

Comment: I'm familiar with Daniels (but  not sure I agree with him).  Does abugida exclude abjadiya?

Comment: would japanese kana stuff count as abugida? I believe it's a lot like ge'ez. (I mean the writing system not the language)

Comment: anyway, I still wanna know what an "inherent vowl" is. ;)

Comment: @mobileink: abjad is the same as abjadiya. Kana is a syllabary. An "inherent vowel" is a vowel that consonants are assumed to have by default without explicit notation in alphabets that have one.

Comment: I think "inherent vowel" means that there's a default value for the vowel in a syllable when it's not otherwise indicated. Like "short a" in Sanskrit. If an abugida always has vowels indicated and never uses a consonant glyph alone in ordinary spelling, it would have no inherent vowel. At least that's the best sense I can make of the term.

Comment: @Anonymous: re: inherent vowels, there is definitely no such thing in Arabic, either written or spoken.  Beware of grand theories of writing systems, they're almost almost wrong even if useful.

Comment: how I hate auto correction!  that should read "almost always".

Comment: just one more point: "syllable" is meaningless in the traditional Arabic analysis.  e.g. "maktab" is two syllables, to a westerner; to an Arab, it is four "terms" - ma, k, ta, b.  Arabic prosodic theory, which is extraordinarily sophisticated,  is founded on this sort of analysis.

Comment: @mobileink: abugida is not arabic. It refers to the brahmic scripts which originate in India e.g. devanagari. In those scripts, consonants are always followed by the vowel /a/, which is changed or muted by diacritics.